# socket.io error "boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()" in react native expo

Tags: react-native, socket.io, expo

i have this error "attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object references when i try to connect socket.io-client. i've no idea why this is happening. can anyone help me.
this is my code

```
    import io from "socket.io-client";
    ...
      useEffect(() => {
        const socket = io("http://192.168.0.138:8080");
        socket.on("msg", () => {
          console.log("socket connected");
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

i recently ran into this issue, nothing is wrong with your code... i don't know if it's a bug fix but i just reinstalled socket.io-client and the error was no more. I actually came across your question while i was searching for a solution lol, and now i found one, helping my fella was what first crossed my mind

Comment: worked in my case but a very weird solution